# Is there a simple line (or two) of code that will pull records before a minimum date in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, claims

I want to pull Emergency room visits before a members **first treatment date**. Everyone as a different first treatment date and none occur before Jan 01 2012.

So if a member has a first treatment date of Feb 24 2013, I want to know how many times they visited the ER one year prior to that date.

These min dates are located in another table and I can not use the Min date in my DATEADD function. Thoughts?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: 7864753590 (ID) 2014-07-01(first treatment date) 4 (number of visits)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use a CTE to capture the visits between the dates your interested in and then join to that with your select.

Here is an example:

[Rextester](https://rextester.com/DLG84251)

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to give this a try!

Comment: It didn't work... I think that taking a step back, I need help select dates that occurred prior to the minimum treatment date located in another table. So I need all of dates that occurred before that date and it's different for every person.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I just completely updated my answer. Sorry for the confusion.

So you have at least two tables:

- Emergency room visits
- Treatment information

Let's call these two tables [ERVisits] and [Treatments].
I suppose both tables have some id-field for the patient/member. Let's call it [MemberId].

How about this conceptual query:

```
WITH [FirstTreatments] AS
(
    SELECT [MemberId], MIN([TreatmentDate]) AS [FirstTreatmentDate]
    FROM [Treatments]
    GROUP BY [MemberId]
)
SELECT V.[MemberId], T.[FirstTreatmentDate], COUNT(*) AS [ERVisitCount]
FROM [ERVisits] AS V INNER JOIN [FirstTreatments] AS T ON T.[MemberId] = V.[MemberId]
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, V.[VisitDate], T.[FirstTreatmentDate]) BETWEEN 0 AND 365
GROUP BY V.[MemberId], T.[FirstTreatmentDate]
```

This query should show the number of times a patient/member has visited the ER in the year before his/her first treatment date.

Here is a tester: https://rextester.com/UXIE4263